# Can't update a Web Dialog Box with iMacros

Tags: imacros

I’m trying to develop a macro to adjust invoices with iMacros.  When I hit the Adjustment button.  I get a Web Page Dialog box and am able to tab, enter and search the first few fields.  When I get the results back, I only get 1 line; which I expect.  So far so good.

The reesults appears in a "new" section of the Web Dialog Box.  The issue I’m having is that I need to check a checkbox on thee only line in the results (2nd section) and haven’t been able to do it so far.

I can't record anything when the Web Dialog Box is open.  If I try and record before hitting the Adjust button, iMacros records hitting the button.  Then I get the Dialog Manager box; which I can use to tab, key and then Enter.  Then I check the checkbox and select another value from a drop down.  I stop recording and nothing has been recorded.

Any suggestions on what is going on?  It's making me crazy.

I'm using iMacros 12

Comment: Your Scenario is a bit vague and difficult to follow without any Script, and no Screenshot, and no URL but I guess the Site is behind L&P... (Name of Invoicing Software/Site...? + Any Demo on Internet...?) - Try using iMB v12.5. - Try the 'EVENT' + 'DS' Modes... - Web Dialogs are specific to IE, try opening this Site (and recording your Actions) in FF and/or CR... - If anything gets dynamically populated (from JS) then some mini-'WAIT' Statements sometimes help but the 'EVENT' Mode is often the only Mode that works a bit correctly with dynamic Elements...

Comment: @chivracq....thanks.......I realized there wasn't a lot of info to go on but you have given me a couple of ideas with Chrome and FireFox.  The application is proprietary so I couldn't show the url.  When I record the steps, iMacros doesn't show any steps recorded.  I can get the top half of the Web Dialog box populated with the Dialog Manager.  Once the results are displayed, it doesn't record any steps in the bottom half of the box, e.g., checking the checkbox, selecting an item from a dropdown.  I'll try your suggestions and see what happens.  Thanks for your help...

Comment: OK, good "luck"... I would need to "see" the Page to be more "helpful"... But the 'EVENT' Mode should be able to record "something", especially with "slow" Clicks (that then get recorded as 'MOUSEMOVE' (instead of 'CLICK') Statements)... Check also if that Web-Dialog maybe has not been coded in 'Flash', or 'Silverlight', or some 'Active-X', then the 'TAG' + 'EVENT' Modes only "see" the HTML Container, and only the 'DS' Mode might be able to interact "inside" that Object...

Comment: @chivracq.......All good info.  Thanks for your insight.  I'll be looking at this again on Monday morning.  Have a good weekend!